# How do you map an enum as string in fluent nhibernate?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Is it possible to map an enum as a string using Fluent Nhibernate?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it does that by default if you just do:

```
Map(x => x.YourProperty);
```

Make sure you're using the latest version off the trunk.

---

As [Yavor Shahpasov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463181/yavor-shahpasov) pointed out in the comments, in more recent versions you can accomplish the same with:

```
Map(x => x.Property).CustomType<GenericEnumMapper<YourPropertyEnumType>>();
```

Comment: That was much easier than I imagined!

Comment: Apparently FluentNHibernate does not do this by default anymore.

Comment: You can do it like this
Map(x => x.Property).CustomType<GenericEnumMapper<EnumType>>();

Answer (score 2):

and there is also the EnumString class you can pass as customType