# Fluent NHibernat - Querying enum field with LINQ

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

My application has the following database structure:

```
Transactions:
- TransactionID (PK, Identity, Int)
- TypeID (FK, Int)
- Amount (Decimal)

TransactionTypes:
- TypeID (PK, Identity, Int)
- Type (NVarChar)
```

They are defined in my application as:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public virtual int TransactionID { get; set; }
    public virtual TransactionTypes Type { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public enum TransactionTypes
{
    Event = 1,
    Product = 2
}
```

With the following mapping:

```
public class TransactionMap : ClassMap<Transaction>
{
    public TransactionMap()
    {
        Table("Transactions");
        Id(x => x.TransactionID);
        Map(x => x.Type, "TypeID").CustomType<int>();
        Map(x => x.Amount);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine apart from querying.  When i try doing:

```
session.Linq<Transaction>().Where(t => t.Type == TransactionTypes.Event).ToList();
```

It throws the error "Type mismatch in `NHibernate.Criterion.SimpleExpression`: Type expected type `System.Int32`, actual type `Entities.TransactionTypes`".

I'd appreciate it if someone could show me the correct way to map this.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to map enums in Fluent NHibernate is by using conventions. See these two threads for help:

[Mapping enum with fluent nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483044/mapping-enum-with-fluent-nhibernate)

[How do you map an enum as an int value with fluent NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439003/how-do-you-map-an-enum-as-an-int-value-with-fluent-nhibernate)