# Fluent nhibernate: Enum in composite key gets mapped to int when I need string

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, composite-key

[By default the behaviour of FNH is to map enums to its string in the db.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503310/how-do-you-map-an-enum-as-string-in-fluent-nhibernate)

But while mapping an enum as part of a composite key, the property gets mapped as int.
e.g.
in this case

```
  public class Address : Entity
  {
    public Address() { }
    public virtual AddressType Type { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

Where AddresType is of

```
  public enum AddressType
  {
    PRESENT, COMPANY, PERMANENT
  }
```

The FNH mapping is as

```
 mapping.CompositeId().KeyReference(x => x.User, "user_id").KeyProperty(x => x.Type);
```

the schema creation of this mapping results in

```
create table address (
    Type INTEGER not null,
   user_id VARCHAR(25) not null,
```

and the hbm as

```
<composite-id mapped="true" unsaved-value="undefined">
  <key-property name="Type" type="Company.Core.AddressType, Company.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
    <column name="Type" />
  </key-property>
  <key-many-to-one name="User" class="Company.Core.CompanyUser, Company.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
    <column name="user_id" />
  </key-many-to-one>
</composite-id>
```

Where the AddressType should have be generated as

```
type="FluentNHibernate.Mapping.GenericEnumMapper`1[[Company.Core.AddressType,
```

**How do I instruct FNH to mappit as the default string enum generic mapper?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[James responded to the answer.](http://support.fluentnhibernate.org/discussions/help/54-enum-in-composite-key-gets-mapped-to-int-when-i-need-string)

Comment: This link is now broken. It would be really nice if answers were actually posted here.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20100706053503/http://support.fluentnhibernate.org/discussions/help/54-enum-in-composite-key-gets-mapped-to-int-when-i-need-string