# Mapping Enum Error FluentNhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I want to Map an `enum` to `mysql` Database.

```
class CommisionWorking
{ 
    public enum Color{ O, PP, FP };
}
```

This is my `mapping` Class.

```
class CommisionWorkingMap : ClassMap<CommisionWorking>
{
    public CommisionWorkingMap()
    {
      Map(x => x.Color).CustomType<typeof(Color));
    }
```

This shows an error. 
Tried

```
Map(x=>x.Color).CustomType<GenericEnumMapper<Color>>
Map(x => x.Color).CustomType();
```

Both Show Error.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, there is nothing different then solution mentioned here:

[Mapping enum with fluent nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1483044/1679310)

So, if the **table** contains **integer** column, we can map it like this:

```
// instead of any of these
// Map(x => x.Color).CustomType<typeof(Color));
// Map(x => x.Color).CustomType<GenericEnumMapper<Color>>
// Map(x => x.Color).CustomType();
// this will map color to integer column with values 0 == O, 1 == PP...
Map(o => o.Color);
```

In case that you have string column (with values O, PP, ...) this your attempt should work:

```
Map(x => x.Color).CustomType<GenericEnumMapper<Color>>
```

As discussed here: [How do you map an enum as string in fluent nhibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/503310/1679310)